# Jacobian and Hessian inputs in `scipy.optimize.minimize`

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, lambda, scipy

I am trying to understand how the "dogleg" method works in Python's [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) function. I am adapting the example at the bottom of the help page.

The dogleg method requires a Jacobian and Hessian argument according to the notes. For this I use the [`numdifftools`](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/numdifftools/latest/numdifftools.pdf) package:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from numdifftools import Jacobian, Hessian

def fun(x,a):
    return (x[0] - 1)**2 + (x[1] - a)**2

x0 = np.array([2,0]) # initial guess
a = 2.5

res = minimize(fun, x0, args=(a), method='dogleg',
               jac=Jacobian(fun)([2,0]), hess=Hessian(fun)([2,0]))

print(res)
```

**Edit:**

If I make a change as suggested by a post below,

```
res = minimize(fun, x0, args=a, method='dogleg',
               jac=Jacobian(lambda x: fun(x,a)),
               hess=Hessian(lambda x: fun(x,a)))
```

I get an error `TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. What am I doing wrong?

Also is it correct to calculate the Jacobian and Hessian at the initial guess `x0`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That error is coming from the calls to `Jacobian` and `Hessian`, not in `minimize`. Replacing `Jacobian(fun)` with `Jacobian(lambda x: fun(x, a))` and similarly for `Hessian` should do the trick (since now the function being differentiated only has a single vector argument).

One other thing: `(a)` is just `a`, if you want it to be a tuple use `(a,)`.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from numdifftools import Jacobian, Hessian

def fun(x, a):
    return (x[0] - 1) **2 + (x[1] - a) **2

def fun_der(x, a):
    return Jacobian(lambda x: fun(x, a))(x).ravel()

def fun_hess(x, a):
    return Hessian(lambda x: fun(x, a))(x)

x0 = np.array([2, 0]) # initial guess
a = 2.5

res = minimize(fun, x0, args=(a,), method='dogleg', jac=fun_der, hess=fun_hess)
print(res)
```

Comment: Thanks. If I make those changes to `Jacobian` and `Hessian` I get an error `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`. Also if I want to specify more than 1 argument, would I then need to use something like `args=(a,b,c)`?

Comment: In this particular case you actually want to pass in a callable Jacobian function so you should leave off the `([2, 0])` (I edited my response to reflect this).

Comment: OK... If I do that, I get `TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. Then if I try using `lambda x,a: fun(x, a)` as the `Jacobian` and `Hessian` inputs I get `ValueError: incompatible dimensions.`

Comment: Thinking a bit more about this: there's really no reason you would ever want to do this anyway. If you don't have a closed-form derivative you should be using a method that doesn't require one; numerically computing the derivatives like this is extremely inefficient.

Comment: Fair point, but I specifically need to solve my problem using the "dogleg" algorithm in Python (which requires the Jacobian and Hessian). I'm not concerned with efficiency of the code yet, I just want to know how the `scipy.optimize.minimize(method='dogleg')` function works.

Comment: I've updated the code to show exactly the steps you need to follow. The `args` parameter is passed to both the Jacobian and Hessian as well, so you have to wrap those in a function that properly handles that argument as well.

Answer (score 12):

I get that this is a toy example, but I would like to point out that using a tool like `Jacobian` or `Hessian` to calculate the derivatives instead of deriving the function itself is fairly costly. For example with your method:

```
x0 = np.array([2, 0])
a = 2.5
%timeit minimize(fun, x0, args=(a,), method='dogleg', jac=fun_der, hess=fun_hess)
100 loops, best of 3: 13.6 ms per loop
```

But you could calculate the derivative functions as such:

```
def fun_der(x, a):
    dx = 2 * (x[0] - 1)
    dy = 2 * (x[1] - a)
    return np.array([dx, dy]

def fun_hess(x, a):
    dx = 2
    dy = 2
    return np.diag([dx, dy])

%timeit minimize(fun, x0, args=(a,), method='dogleg', jac=fun_der, hess=fun_hess)
1000 loops, best of 3: 279 µs per loop
```

As you can see that is almost 50x faster. It really starts to add up with complex functions. As such I always try to derive the functions explicitly myself, regardless of how difficult that may be. One fun example is the kernel based implementation of [Inductive Matrix Completion](http://bigdata.ices.utexas.edu/publication/1600/).

```
argmin --> sum((A - gamma_u(X) Z gamma_v(Y))**2 - lambda * ||Z||**2)
where gamma_u = (1/sqrt(m_x)) * [cos(UX), sin(UX)] and
gamma_v = (1/sqrt(m_y)) * [cos(VY), sin(VY)]
X.shape = n_x, p; Y.shape = n_y, q; U.shape = m_x, p; V.shape = m_y, q; Z.shape = 2m_x, 2m_y
```

Calculating the gradient and hessian from this equation is extremely unreasonable in comparison to explicitly deriving and utilizing those functions. So as @bnaul pointed out, if your function does have closed form derivates you really do want to calculate and use them.

Comment: don't know `numdifftools`, but couldn't you calculate `jacf = Jacobian(lambda x: fun(x,  2.5))` just once, then `minimize( ... jac=jacf, hess=hessf )` ?

Comment: @denis I think you meant to direct that towards bnaul I don't use numdifftools or these methods. As I mention, I like to derive the functions directly if possible to avoid the overhead of repeatedly calculating them at each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You can use autograd instead

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from autograd import jacobian, hessian

def fun(x, a):
    return (x[0] - 1) **2 + (x[1] - a) **2

def fun_der(x, a):
    return jacobian(lambda x: fun(x, a))(x).ravel()

def fun_hess(x, a):
    return hessian(lambda x: fun(x, a))(x)

x0 = np.array([2, 0]) # initial guess
a = 2.5

res = minimize(fun, x0, args=(a,), method='dogleg', jac=fun_der, hess=fun_hess)
print(res)
```

Comment: Would be great with some more explanation on this answer, just posting code has limited usefulness.